# MongoDB Optional Partial Unique Index in Nested Arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am trying to create a solution for a unique partial index on `token` field in a nested array `apps.tokens`, such that the nested array `tokens` is optional or can be empty.

I create the index as:

```
collection.createIndex(
        Indexes.ascending("apps.tokens.token"),
        new IndexOptions()
                .unique(true)
                .partialFilterExpression(
                        Filters.type("apps.tokens.token", BsonType.STRING)
                )
);
```

The value of the field `apps.tokens.token` is never explicitly `null` and will always be some unique string. I am currently not worried about duplicates within the same document.

However, I can't get the partial index to behave the way I would expect. It is mostly working as intended, except for situations when there is an item in the `apps` array with an empty or missing `tokens` array.

Creating the following structure fails with error `E11000 duplicate key error collection: db1.testCollection index: apps.tokens.token_1 dup key: { apps.tokens.token: null }` :

```
[
    {
        "apps": [
            {
                "client_id": "capp1",
                "tokens": [
                    {
                        "token": "t1",
                        "expiration": "2020-09-10T23:31:17.119+01:00"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "client_id": "capp2"
            }
        ],
        "uuid": "89337f58-a491-4e17-b8dd-726c9319dcaa"
    },
    {
        "apps": [
            {
                "client_id": "capp3",
                "tokens": [
                    {
                        "token": "t2",
                        "expiration": "2020-09-10T23:31:17.119+01:00"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "client_id": "capp4"
            }
        ],
        "uuid": "4ccc4d81-990f-4650-b26e-1d26fd22d91a"
    }
]
```

However, this structure is perfectly valid according to the same index:

```
[
    {
        "apps": [
            {
                "client_id": "capp1"
            },
            {
                "client_id": "capp2"
            }
        ],
        "uuid": "89337f58-a491-4e17-b8dd-726c9319dcaa"
    },
    {
        "apps": [
            {
                "client_id": "capp3"
            },
            {
                "client_id": "capp4"
            }
        ],
        "uuid": "4ccc4d81-990f-4650-b26e-1d26fd22d91a"
    }
]
```

My guess is that the first test case fails, because, having the first item inserted, the index checks that it has a `apps.token.token` field that is a String and adds this whole document to the insert/update comparison.

On the other hand, the second test case does not fail, because none of the documents match the condition of `apps.tokens.token` being a String.

As it looks at the second item to be inserted, it somehow deduces that it has a `apps.token.token` field that is implicitly `null` (because there is no `tokens` array in one of the `apps` items), then it checks whether the existing item matches `{"apps.tokens.token": null}` and indeed it does, and ends the operation in a failure.

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried to create the partial index with `exists` filter too, but it does not help.

```
Filters.and(
        Filters.type("apps.tokens.token", BsonType.STRING),
        Filters.exists("apps.tokens.token"),
        Filters.exists("apps.tokens")
)
```

Is it possible to supplement the filter with some sort of function that will handle cases when `tokens` does not exist or is empty for each `apps` item in a document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution may be to use a `sparse` index, although the official documentation states:

> Partial indexes offer a superset of the functionality of sparse
> indexes. If you are using MongoDB 3.2 or later, partial indexes should
> be preferred over sparse indexes.

My tests are passing with:

```
collection.createIndex(
        Indexes.ascending("apps.tokens.token"),
        new IndexOptions()
                .unique(true)
                .sparse(true)
);
```

I wonder if this has any other implications that are not currently obvious to me.

For the fullness of the solution, note that the index addresses uniqueness across documents. However, it won't check for uniqueness within the same document, so it would be possible to add a token that already exists in one of the apps in the same document. To work around this issue, I add a filter to the update query, such that a document that already has a token I'm trying to add is not included in the documents that would be updated:

```
Document doc = Document.parse("{\"token\":\"t1\"}");
collection.updateOne(
        Filters.and(
                Filters.eq("uuid", "89337f58-a491-4e17-b8dd-726c9319dcaa"),
                Filters.not(Filters.eq("apps.tokens.token", "t1"))
        ),

        Updates.push("apps.$[app].tokens", doc),
        new UpdateOptions().arrayFilters(Arrays.asList(
                Filters.eq("app.client_id", "capp1")
        ))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of an index in MongoDB is to map specific values to documents.

In the case of an index on an array (multikey index) there will be multiple values in the index for a single document.

An example:

**Documents**

```
#1 { apps: [
         { tokens: [
                  {token: "T1"},
                  {token: "T2"}
         ]},
         { tokens: [] }
    ]},
#2 { apps: [
         { tokens: [
                  {token: "T3"},
                  {token: "T4"}
         ]},
         { notokens: true }
    ])
#3 { apps: [
         { notokens: true }
         { notokens: true }
   ]}
#4 { apps: [
         { tokens: [
                  { token: "T5" },
                  { token: "T5" }
          ]}
   ]}
```

**Index**

If we create an index on `{"apps.tokens.token": 1}`, the index will have the following:

```
NULL -> #1
NULL -> #2
NULL -> #3
"T1" -> #1
"T2" -> #1
"T3" -> #2
"T4" -> #2
"T5" -> #4
```

**Unique**

If we had instead created that index with a unique constraint, document #2 and #3 would have been both rejected because they would have caused the `NULL` value to be duplicated in the index.

Note that document #4 would be accepted.  Since it is the value entered into the index that must be unique, and a value is only indexed once for a given document, the `"T5"` is not duplicated in the index even though it appears twice in the document, so this does not violate the unique constraint.

**Partial**

A partial index filter is matched against the document as a whole.  If the filter matches, the document included in the index.

If we create the index with the partial filter `{"apps.tokens.token":{$type:"string"}}`, it is matched in the same manner as if we had passed it to `find`, i.e. if any element of the array matches, the document is matched.

This would mean that documents #1, #2, and #4 would be included in the index, while #3 would be excluded.

If we had made the index both partial and unique, documents #1, #3, and #4 would be accepted, and #2 would be rejected for duplicating the `NULL` value.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise that index is a map. Thanks for the insight